# IIS8 'HTTP Error 503 - Service unavailable' when using ApplicationPoolIdentity or a custom account, but not when using NetworkService

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET application on Windows Server 2012 (with IIS 8) but I'm getting an http error 503 when using the ApplicationPoolIdentity or a custom account, but not with NetworkService.

In order to narrow down the problem I set up a simple one page html application under the Default Web Site. This exhibits the same behaviour. I've given the custom account and the application pool identity full permissions on the application folder(s).

I've also checked the Windows event log and get this error: the worker process failed to initialize correctly the data is the error. 05000780. The application pool is stopped each time I try to browse the site (using applicationpoolidentity).

Comment: Probably a file system level permission problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055 (second table row)

Comment: Thanks Laszlo, but that appears to be a different error.

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure that the filesystem location has permissions for the user that you're trying to use?

NetworkService often has the correct permissions, but a new account most likely won't.

Comment: Yes, the application folder has permissions for both the application pool identity and the custom account.

Comment: Did you check to make sure the permission is applied to all sub-items?

Comment: Yes, permissions given to all sub-directories. I'm wondering if I need the user to have batch logon rights.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the custom account to "Logon as a batch job" and all is now working.